# Simplest of backbone.js examples

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating a bare bones [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone) example to try to learn it and am having issues getting my view to render.  I've based it on Thomas Davis's [tutorial](http://thomasdavis.github.com/2011/02/01/backbone-introduction.html) but looked at many of the other apps and tutorials available.

I'm changing Davis's tutorial not only because I want to add an input box, but also because based on the backbone docs I thought it needed less code and a different structure.  Obviously because I can't get this to work, I don't know what's needed and what isn't.

My ultimate goal was to just add the names in `li` tags within `ul#friends-list`, although I don't think `el: 'body'` will help me there.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help.

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tut</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter friend's name" id="input" />
<button id="add-input">Add Friend</button>

<ul id="friends-list">
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My test.js

```
$(function() {

Friend = Backbone.Model.extend();
//Create my model

var friends = new Friend([ {name: 'Eddard Stark'}, {name: 'Robert Baratheon'} ]);
//Create new models to be used as examples


FriendList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Friend
});
//Create my collection

var friendslist = new FriendList;
//Created to hold my friends model


FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click #add-input':  'getFriend',
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    }, 

    getFriend: function() {
        var friend_name = $('#input').val();
        var friend_model = new Friend({name: friend_name});
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('rendered')
    },

});

var view = new FriendView({el: 'body'});
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I can't get my view to render.  How do I get the models to list in the `ul`?

Comment: First of all you have only written a view for an individual Friend. You have not written a view for the collection ( FriendList ). There is no magic in backbone wrt views. You have to build them manually. This means you need a "class FriendListView extends Backbone.View" with a render method that iterates through the collection and appends <li> items to the ul

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You had some fundamental problems with your code to get the functionality that you required.   I turned your code into a jsfiddle and you can see the working solution here.

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/Yqk5A/

**Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tut</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter friend's name" id="input" />
<button id="add-input">Add Friend</button>

<ul id="friends-list">
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(function() {

FriendList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){

    }
});

FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    events: {
        'click #add-input':  'getFriend',
    },

    initialize: function() {
        var thisView = this;
        this.friendslist = new FriendList;
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.friendslist.bind("add", function( model ){
            alert("hey");
            thisView.render( model );
        })
    },

    getFriend: function() {
        var friend_name = $('#input').val();
        this.friendslist.add( {name: friend_name} );
    },

    render: function( model ) {
        $("#friends-list").append("<li>"+ model.get("name")+"</li>");
        console.log('rendered')
    },

});

var view = new FriendView({el: 'body'});
});
```

I noticed that you wanted as little code as possible so I left some things out that you don't need such as declaring an actual model.   It might be easier if you use a collection like in the example instead.

Also I have just launched a new site containing Backbone tutorials which might help solve your problem.

[BackboneTutorials.com](http://backbonetutorials.com)

Comment: I think there is problem with that code. I don't see why Collection would ever call to view. I think view should listen to add event on collection and rerender.

Comment: And collection also depends on name of variable holding reference to the view.

Comment: @ThomasDavis From you I got to know jsfiddle.net. Handy thing to work in JS. Cheers